# Add new column as the difference between two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with daily time series in PostgreSQL.
My goal is to add a new variable to my table, which computes the difference between the value of a certain column for two adjacent dates for the same company. (You can e.g. think of a growth rate)

We can think of the following example data:

```
  date company value

  2012-01-01       A  5
  2012-01-01       B  2
  2012-01-01       C  3
  2012-01-02       A  4
  2012-01-02       B  2
  2012-01-02       C  4
  2012-01-03       A  7
  2012-01-03       B  2
  2012-01-03       C  2
```

The optimal result I want to achieve is:

```
   date      company value  diff
  2012-01-01       A  5     NULL
  2012-01-01       B  2     NULL
  2012-01-01       C  3     NULL
  2012-01-02       A  4     -1
  2012-01-02       B  2      0
  2012-01-02       C  4      1
  2012-01-03       A  7      3
  2012-01-03       B  2      0 
  2012-01-03       C  2     -2
```

I tried the following (probably very cumbersome) approach:

1. Added an autoincrement primary key to identify each row

   ```
   CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq;
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD id INT UNIQUE;
   ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('id_seq');          
   UPDATE mytable SET id = NEXTVAL('id_seq');
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
   ```
2. Computed the differences in the following way:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE change AS WITH d AS (SELECT value, id FROM temp)
   SELECT d.value - d2.value AS change FROM d d
   JOIN d d2 ON d.id = d2.id + 1;
   ```

Unfortunately that code doesn't manage to distinguish between the different companies and computes the differences between all adjacent rows. Furthermore I don't know how to add it to the existing table, since it doesn't fill in the first value with NULL but skips it and starts with the second row, such that the resulting table is one row too short.

Can you think of any other effective approach to find a solution?

Comment: This is an ideal candidate for the `lag()` window function. And I really recommend *not* adding the diff to the table, it's a horrible denormalization. Use a view over a window query, or if you need to cache it, a materialized view.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working perfectly. Why would it be better to use a view instead of adding the diff to the table? @CraigRinger

Comment: It makes the rows interdependent; when you remove a row, other rows become incorrect. It also duplicates information. It's something you could do as a performance optimisation if you had to, after considering the alternatives, it just should not be the first choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` or `LAG()`:

```
SELECT date
     , company 
     , value
     , value - LAG(value,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY date) AS Val_Diff
FROM YourTable
```

More examples of each here:  [Lag-Lead Analytic Functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php)

Comment: Shouldn't that be PARTITION BY company ORDER BY date ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt just noticed that myself. Also based on example should be LAG instead of LEAD.

Comment: Gah, beat me to it. Here's the SQLFiddle from my answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/374f0/2